How to link to libpq postgresql c library for postgresql v17.1?
I'm trying to compile and link c program that access postgresql database, calls a function from database and outputs the result of the function. I'm following documentation as stated here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-example.html and here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/17/libpq-build.html. Here is the code of my program:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libpq-fe.h"

static void Terminate(PGconn* conn) {
  PQfinish(conn);
  exit(1);
}

int main() {
  const char* conn_info = "dbname = myDB";
  PGconn* conn;
  PGresult* res;
  int nfields;

  conn = PQconnectdb(conn_info);
  if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
    printf("%s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    Terminate(conn);
  }

  res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false)");
  if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
    printf("%s", PQerrorMessage(conn));
    PQclear(res);
    Terminate(conn);
  }
  PQclear(res);

  while (1 == 1) {
    int command_code;
    printf("Enter command code:\n");
    scanf("%d", &command_code);
    switch (command_code) {
      case 1: // Fetch something.
        res = PQexec(conn, "SELECT my_function();");
        if (PQresultStatus(res) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK) {
          PQerrorMessage(conn);
          PQclear(res);
          Terminate(conn);
        }
        nfields = PQnfields(res);
        for (int i = 0; i < nfields; ++i) {
          printf("%-15s", PQfname(res, i));
          printf("\n\n");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < PQntuples(res); i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < nfields; j++) printf("%-15s", PQgetvalue(res, i, j));
          printf("\n");
        }
        PQclear(res);
        break;
      case 0:
        Terminate(conn);
        break;
      default:
        printf("Unknown command.\n");
        break;
    } 
  }
}

I'm compiling it using 'clang' compiler on OS 'Windows' with following command:
clang Main.c -o server.obj -I 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\include'

I'm trying to link produced server.obj file to library with following command:
clang -o server server.obj -L 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib' -lpq

Program compiles just fine, but I get errors on linking. Following is the part of wall of errors that i get:
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xc7): undefined reference to `__imp_select'  
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xd3): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xe0): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x12d): undefined reference to `__security_check_cookie'
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x7f): undefined reference to `libintl_dgettext'
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0xd1): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x10): undefined reference to `__security_cookie'
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x191): undefined reference to `__imp_select' 
C:/Software/MSYS2/ucrt64/bin/ld: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib/libpq.a(src/interfaces/libpq/libpq.a.p/fe-misc.c.obj):(.text$mn+0x19d): undefined reference to `__imp_WSAGetLastError'

Should linker resolve all undefined references by itself? If I specify include directory itself without specifying all the object files to be linked (if neeed - in order) shouldn't linker link it properly? What link command should I use to make it finally link?
If needed here are programs versions:
PostgreSQL 17.1;
clang 19.1.3.
While searching for the solutions I learned that order in which you specify linked object files actually matter and so your program should be specified first and then all the linked files should be specified in dependecy order: dependent after dependepcy provider. I also found this 2 posts: https://libpqxx-general.gborg.postgresql.narkive.com/pgLhr8zR/lots-of-undefined-references-linking-with-mingw-msys and https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CACS8yHKjrFOoTKKFOOted4d%2B16oN438DE0ydtp9y5QrxvcGp2w%40mail.gmail.com from where I saw that linking libpq also required linking to lpgport and lpgcommon. I changed my linking command to clang -o server server.obj -L 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\17\lib' -lpgport -lpgcommon -lpq but it made no difference. I tried putting linked files in different order but it didn't work. I tried using gcc compiler too and got same errors. I have no clue what causes that linking errors. My postgress (which I downloaded from official site on 19.11.2024) works just fine but I can't use it's API because of this error. Any suggestions on how to make it link? 5 hours in this error, would appreciate any help

Solved the problem by downgrading to postgreSQL 16.4. After installing version 16.4 I followed through docs tutorial 'libpq-build' and my app linked without any 'undefined reference' or 'undefined symbol' errors with linker commands presented in the docs.
